# Mysql query select where expression

Tags: mysql, database, select

I select from one table only the rows that are experiencing some arithmetic expression. For example: I have a table with 600 million rows. each line contains two coordinates (x, y), in a file php I restuire only the rows that have this point (x, y) within a radius.

how could I do?

Comment: Is the centre (xc, yc) going to be constant over your application needs? Assuming `root((xc - x)^2 + (yc - y)^2) <= r`?

Comment: exactly. step in a php file a point (x, y) constant that corresponds to the center, and a radius. the php file through query must restuire table rows that have their point (x, y) inside the circle of radius R.

Comment: My question was : Is (xc, yc) constant forever? If not, it may not be possible to make use of the index. And scanning 600 million rows would take huge amount of time. You will have to identify certain heuristics to partition the data for quick accesses.